# Краткая и полная статья

Tags: php, mysql, cms, livestreet

Всем привет, хочу обратится к велосипедистам, пишу модуль для работы со статьями, нужно как-то вывести краткую версию статьи и потом на другой странице всю статью целиком, подумывал порезать статью с помощью функций, но тогда краткие будут одного размера и будет не красиво, видал  на CMF LiveStreet, подобную вещь, когда мы пишем статью, где на нужно сделать разделитель пишем тег <cat> и всё, всё что до этого тега, будет отдельно. Как реализовать подобное, делать 2 поля с краткой и полной версией не вариант, прошу помочь)

Comment: Все обычно твердят, что когда одинаково - как раз красиво))

Выбираете содержимое и делаете что-то типа explode('<cat>', $content)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все довольно просто, там где нужно выводить вступительный текст, код такой

```
$text = 'Я вступительный текст.<cut />А я текст после подробнее...';

if(strpos($text, '<cut />'))
{
    $text = explode('<cut />', $text);
    echo $text[0];
}
else
{
    echo $text;//Если вдруг отсутствует тег <cut />
}
```

Там где нужно выводить полный текст, черпаем весть текст из БД.

Answer (score 1):

Как раз сейчас с такой же задачей столкнулся. Сделал разделение вступления и остального по тегу (у меня это `<hr id="system-readmore" />`) и если он присутствует в статье, бьётся по нему, если нет — по длине.

Может, заодно, пригодится ф-я, ограничивающая по длине, с учётом целостности слов:

```
function limiter( $text, $limit=100) { 
    $strLength = mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8');
    if( $strLength > $limit) {
        $text = mb_substr($text, 0, $limit, 'UTF-8');
        $pos = mb_strrpos($text, ' ', false, 'UTF-8');
        if($pos === false) {
            $text = mb_substr($text, 0, $limit, 'UTF-8').'...';
        } else {
            $text = mb_substr($text, 0, $pos, 'UTF-8').'...';
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Такие перлы могут получаться при автоматическом обрезании, что даже не смешно становится. IMHO, вредная штука, поэтому либо по явному месту <cut>, либо вообще summary вводить отдельным блоком.

Comment: Понятно, что лучше избегать автоматики в том, что касается человеческого языка. Это лишь вариант отступления, на случай, если нет ката.